# Refactoring out part of async method to lambda

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

I'm fairly new to the concept of `async` and `await`. Right now I've got something like this:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{
    using (var obj = new SomeClass())
    {
        await obj.SomeAction();
    }

    Done = true;
}
```

But as the creation and management of the `obj` object is becoming more complex, I would like to refactor it to something like this:

```
public async void DoSomething()
{
    Manager.Execute(obj =>
    {
        await obj.SomeAction();
    });

    Done = true;
}
```

But the above code won't compile. It surely lacks some `async` or `await` keywords here or there. I also don't know how to write the `Execute()` method. Can you help?

Comment: You should avoid `async void`. It doesn't allow the caller to know when it completes, has difficult exception handling semantics, cannot be used in unit tests, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to use `await` in lambdas, you have to decorate them with the `async` modifier, just like a method:

```
Func<Task<Foo>> asyncFooFactory = async () => await whatever;
```

And the `Execute` method would then look like this:

```
// instead of Task, you could use void, but then you can't await its completion,
// which could get handy later, depending on your use case
public static async Task Execute(Func<YourClass, Task> externalStuff)
{
    using (var obj = new YourClass()) // replace with your own initializer code
    {
        await externalStuff(obj);
    }
}
```